# Get SercurityException of READ_CONTACTS on android lower than 6.0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentprovider, android-workmanager

My application's Fabric Crashlytics keeps appearing SercurityException permission denial of READ_CONTACTS when I try to query contact information from ContentProvider. The weird thing is the logs show that all those things happened on android lower than Marshmallow (5.1.1 specifically), both rooted and non-rooted, which doesn't make any sense since Runtime permission is only required on android from 6.0 and above.

I'm never able to reproduce the issue. Get like thousand of logs on fabric and I never get any real one on all of my devices no matter how hard I tried.

The operations run in a Worker instance which is derived from RxWorker of WorkerManager framework. Start with function createWork like this

```
override fun createWork(): Single<Result> {
        if (!isContactPermissionGranted()) {
            return Single.just(Result.failure())
        }

        return Observable.create { 
            it.onNext(contactFetcher.fetchAll())
            it.onComplete()
        }
        .flatMap { // Do something with the data }
        .map { Result.success() }
        .onErrorReturn { Result.failure() }       
}
```

Here is the function fetchAll in contactFetcher

```
public ArrayList<Contact> fetchAll() throws Exception {

        String[] projectionFields = new String[]{
                ...
        };
        ...
        Cursor c = null;
        try {
            c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projectionFields, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
            if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
                // Do something with the return cursor...
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                c.close();
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

This is the crashlytics log:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException
Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{3bd623d1 11061:vn.com/u0a175} (pid=11061, uid=10175) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

And yes I did put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />` in my manifest

Comment: the `AndroidManifest.xml` would be rather interesting, because it may lack the permission.

Comment: Edited answer. I did put permission in ```AndroidManifest.xml```

Answer (score 0):

Please add following permissions in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Following java code is working my side

```
private ArrayList<Contacts> fetchAll() {
    ArrayList<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = null;
    try {
        c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {

            do {

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: Edited answer. I put them in my ```AndroidManifest.xml``` before and still getting the issue.

Comment: My current code is also working on my devices. But I got like thousands of issue on fabric crashlytics of my users